# Android app error in eclipse

Tags: android

Can someone help me with this problem

> android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar

facing it again and again.
Installed all the `SDK tools`, but with no success.

Comment: Have you included the v7 support library in your project?

Comment: Can you help me with it, because I'm a newbie in the development world so don't have an idea of it

Comment: why don't you use Android Studio??

Comment: As @Coeus already said, it is better to use Android Studio. Because Android Studio is Google's official Android IDE.

Comment: It uses a lot of ram i have installed it but it lagged like hell on my pc because it has only 2gb of ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things that can be happening:

- You are extending `ActionBarActivity`, change that to `Activity`
- Your target sdk version in the manifest is a different value than the sdk version you selected when you created the app
- Try to have an api level of above 14 (This you should do at absolutely last attempt

**Here are some things that you can easily do to fix it:**

- Clean project
- Rebuild Project
- RESTART YOUR IDE
- If you are using eclipse, you should probably be using android studio
- Reinstall sdk manager (Only if nothing else works)

Chances are, you just need to restart android studio. If this answers your question, make sure to mark it best answer. If you need any more help, feel free to ask me!

Comment: Thnx bro it worked the problem was with the minimum and target sdk . Since android studio needs a lot of ram I cannot use it because I have only 2gb of ram. Is it possible to work with eclipse for any android app. Want to make a file manager, can u help me in getting some videos or guides to start my work. Thnx once again

Comment: @PratikGhagare No Problem. I suggest watching The New Boston tutorials from youtube (as that is what I used). Also, just do some google searches on File Manager's (Only do that once you know the basics). Also, I don't suggest using eclipse for android programming, it's outdated. You **can** use eclipse, but I suggest not to. Instead, you should use Android Studio.

Comment: Will it work with 2gb of ram

Comment: @PratikGhagare  I don't know if it will run but if it does it will run  very slowly especially the emulator

Comment: @PratikGhagare I suggest you just try it out

Comment: Yup i tried it worked but emulator was very slow in loading thnx for your suggestion